# change color button with corner rounder

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found this code:
XAML:

```
<Button Content="Click Me!" Margin="209,135,263.4,140.8" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="Button_Click_1">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="bdr_main" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightGray">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

It’s possible to change color of background with WTF code?
I clicked on the button, the background color change.

With the normal button 
I can use this code:
            bdr_main.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
Or
            bdr_main.Background = Brushes.Red;
but he doesn’t work
Can you help me?

Comment: change the Border to use TemplateBinding rather than Background="LightGray"

Comment: I’m sorry
Your code worked 
Thx a lot
Do you have the same solution with WPF code ?

Comment: your Xaml looks like WPF ???  No.

Comment: Yes but
Somme like exemple :
bdr_main.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
I would have a better mastery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ToggleButton and it's IsChecked property

```
<ToggleButton Content="Click Me!" Margin="209,135,263.4,140.8">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border x:Name="bdr_main" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0" 
                    Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to change the Background Color from code behind, you'll need to implement it's TemplateBinding

```
prop="{TemplateBinding Background}
```

Stripping the XAML down to the bones

```
<ToggleButton Click="Button_Click" Content="Click Me!"
              Background="LightGray" Margin="209,135,263.4,140.8">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border x:Name="bdr_main" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Now you can

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

...

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var butt = sender as ToggleButton;
    if ((bool)butt.IsChecked)
        butt.Background = Brushes.Red;
    else
        butt.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
}
```

The MouseOver event is best handled in the ControlTemplate, to obtain the same behavior as in my first post you can change it to

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border x:Name="bdr_main" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I’m sorry Your code worked Thx a lot Do you have the same solution with WPF code ?

Comment: Hello,
exactly what I wanted Thx for your 
thx for your wonderful help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit changed to ToggleButton per OP follow up

Just add a setter to your trigger.

```
        <ToggleButton Content="Click Me!" Margin="209,135,263.4,140.8" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="Button_Click_1">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="bdr_main" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightGray">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>

                            //Add line below
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Edit
You no longer need to do this

If you wanted to do it in code behind on the click event handler; note this behavior is different from the trigger above, background will stay red.

```
Button_Click_1(sender, e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Background = Colors.Red;
```

Comment: Thx for your help but it’s the same, i searched an solution with the wpf code for exemple :
The button name with .Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
But WPF not recognized name bdr_main

Comment: Can you describe how it's not working?  When you press on the button it doesn't turn red?  Once you release the mouse, the color changes back to light gray.  Did you wanted to color to remain red after you release the button?

Comment: It's the same because when I click on the button click the red color appear but after the light gray re-back
For your code too
It’s possible 
I want the red color stay when I click on the button
I searched the possible code for change color on the same button or other button.
Maybe it’s more easy with the WPF code  no ?

Comment: Your code :
Button_Click_1(sender, e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Background = Colors.Red;
Worked with the normal button but not with the button code to up
Do you have another solution please ?

Comment: I resumed the situation
Hi, your code with xamp worked. 
Your code with WPF not worked
Maybe I not understand
Can you explain me you wpf code please ?